# Receive a http post in BizTalk orchestration

Tags: wcf, http-post, biztalk, xmldocument

I have a wcf restful service that accepts http posts.

I am trying to send this to an orchestration with a rcv message set as XmlDocument. (Since no subscribers where found when set to system.string)

The message is received in the orchestration but the xmldocument is invalid so its not possible to do anything with the data(Im sending a string in the http post). (When I attempt it I get an error that the data at the root level is invalid).

How can I get the http post string into my orchestration? Do I need to add a custom pipelinecomponent that adds xml tags to the string to make it a valid XmlDocument?

Comment: You will have to find out exactly what the content of the message is when it hits the Orchestration before anyone can answer this.  The easiest way is to Stop (don't Unenlist) the Orchestration and examine the suspended message.

Comment: The body of the message Parts is exactly the same string that is sendt in the http post to the service. I am using wcf-webHttp at the receive location.

Comment: Have you tried using the XmlDisassembler?  It's unusual take xml as a string in an Orchestration.

Comment: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data. Is it no easy way to do this? Do I have to make a flat file schema xsd out of nthe string?

Comment: Hold on, is the context Xml or 'flat file' type?  If it's not Xml, then yes, you will need to parse it to xml first with the Flat File Disassembler and a matching Flat File Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Created a flat file schema where the string in the http post is added to one line. Added a pipeline with a flat file dissasembler with the schema. Use xpath in orchestration to retrieve the string.